# get extra field value in Django's many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

In Django's many-to-many relationships extra fields, we can add extra fields, as the code below (from  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany), my question is how could I get the extra field easily, is it possible to not query on the intermediary table directly? the exactly example is:

```
>>> ringo = Person.objects.create(name="Ringo Starr")
>>> paul = Person.objects.create(name="Paul McCartney")
>>> beatles = Group.objects.create(name="The Beatles")
>>> m1 = Membership(person=ringo, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1962, 8, 16),
...     invite_reason="Needed a new drummer.")
>>> m1.save()
>>> beatles.members.all()
[<Person: Ringo Starr>]

>>> p = beatles.members.all()[0]
>>> p
[<Person: Ringo Starr>]
```

I want to get the date_joined value of p, I know it can be done by

```
>>> Membership.objects.get(person=p, group=beatles).date_joined
datetime.date(1962, 8, 16)
```

but is it possible to get it simply just like:

```
>>> p.xxx(*args)
```

=============== models.py ================

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you want to access this? For example are you looking for context in a view that will return the date the current user joined any group they're in? I ask because your use of `p` in the question is confusing me. Following from the example you gave the answer would just be `p.date_joined`.

Comment: not exactly, there is no p.date_joined available, since date_joined field is in Membership table (for each Person, it could have multiple records and multiple date_joined value since it can join multiple Groups), Person table only record the person name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation page you link to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany):

Another way to access the same information is by querying the many-to-many reverse relationship from a Person object:

```
>>> ringos_membership = ringo.membership_set.get(group=beatles)
>>> ringos_membership.date_joined
datetime.date(1962, 8, 16)
>>> ringos_membership.invite_reason
'Needed a new drummer.'
```