# Displaying data from intermediate table in a many-to-many relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have 3 models that follow the principle described in Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='Interest')

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField('Topic', through='Interest')

class Interest(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.ForeignKey(TopicSource, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

---

The `views.py`is really simple:

```
class TopicsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'app/topics.html'
    context_object_name = 'topics_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Topic.objects.all()
```

---

The template is actually giving me headaches:

```
    <table>
        <tbody class="list">
            {% for item in topics_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.person_set.all.count }}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        {% for person in item.person_set.all %}
                        <li>{{ person.last_name }}, {{ person.first_name }} [{% person.interests_set.get(cluster=item) %}]</li>{% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

With `{% person.interests_set.get(topic=item) %}`, I'm trying to access data from the intermediate table.

How can I display the `source` of the `interest` next to the name of the person?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552526/get-extra-field-value-in-djangos-many-to-many-relationship) is giving hint on how to do this from the shell but I cannot figure out how to achieve that in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django templates don't support what you're trying to do out of the box. You would have to create a custom [tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#tags) to implement what you're trying.

However you could do:

```
class TopicsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'app/topics.html'
    context_object_name = 'topics_list'
    queryset = Topic.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'interest_set',
            Interest.objects.select_related('person')
    )
```

Then adjust your template to iterate over the interests.

```
<table>
    <tbody class="list">
        {% for item in topics_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.interest_set.all.count }}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    {% for interest in item.interest_set.all %}
                    <li>{{ interest.person.last_name }}, {{ interest.person.first_name }} [ {{ interest.source }} ]</li>{% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution proposed by @schillingt (the accepted solution), I came up with the below solution:

`views.py`:

```
class InterestsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'app/interests.html'
    context_object_name = 'interests_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Interest.objects.order_by('topic', 'person').all()
```

template:

```
{% regroup interests_list by topic as l1%}
    <table>
        <tbody>
            {% for topic in l1 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ topic.grouper }}</td>
                <td>{{ topic.list|length }}</td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        {% for item in topic.list%}
                        <li>{{ item.person.last_name }}, {{ item.person.first_name }} [{{ item.source }}]</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

However, the solution from @schillingt is better since it's performance are a lot better (by a factor 2),